# Initialize a hover state only once the mouse has clicked and moused out of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I have a simple link that toggles on each click. There's also a hover state that gets added to the link when it is in the 'clicked' state. See example below:

```
<style>
  .added {
    &:hover {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
</style>

<script>
  $('a').on('click', function() {

    var $link = $(this);

    if ( $link.hasClass('added') ) {

      $link
        .removeClass('added')
        .html('Add Me!')

    } else {

      $link
        .addClass('added')
        .html('Added');

  });
</script>

<a href='#'>Add Me!</a>
```

The challenge here, is that I'd like the button *not* to turn red immediately after clicking 'Add Me!' (as the mouse is technically still hovering over the link). It should only turn red once I've clicked, moved off and then returned.

Is there a clean way to do this using either CSS and/or jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with jQuery's `mouseout()` function.

Here I've modified your existing code (with some minor fixes) to include a check on mouseout to add a `.ready` class:

```
  $('a').click(function() {
    var link = $(this);
    if ( link.hasClass('added') ) {
      link.removeClass('added').removeClass('ready').html('Add Me!');
    } else {
      link.addClass('added').html('Added');
      // Check if .ready is applied already
      if(!link.hasClass('ready')){
        link.mouseout(function(){
          link.addClass('ready');
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

and modified your SASS to include `.ready`:

```
  .added.ready{
    &:hover {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
```

You can see it in action on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/easL77fa/

Comment: This solution is pretty close. You'll need to remove the mouseout event in addition to the classes. When toggling back to 'Add Me!' and mousing out, the 'ready' class is again placed on the link. This causes it to immediately turn red the next time instead of waiting for mouseout.